# Two different resolution displays nvidia x server overlap on startup

Tags: xorg, nvidia, display-settings

I Have a 2k display and a 4k display used with Pop!_OS 20.04. I have set up my xorg.conf file to set my ViewPortIn to 4k to allow for consistent DPI scaling and mouse movements between the screens. This works great.

The problem becomes when I boot the left screen (2K monitor) is overlapping about a 1/4 to a 1/3 of the right screen (4K monitor). So every time I turn on my computer I have to go into the NVIDIA X Server Settings and drag the left screen over so it aligns correctly. See the pictures below.

Here is the relevant line from xorg.conf file.

`Option         "metamodes" "DP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {viewportin=3840x2160}, HDMI-0:`

Right after boot
[image: Right after boot]
After I manually fix the overlap
[image]

Is there a way I can set the config file or another setting to stop this overlap every time I boot?